# X11: Get Window Position, Width and Height via ID

Tags: c++, linux, x11

I have a GTK Application. Now I need to give the Window ID via IPC to another process. I am getting the XID of the window by using the GDKx function

```
GDK_WINDOW_XID(::gtk_widget_get_window(GTK_WIDGET(widget)));
```

Is there any XLib or XCB function that allows me to get the position and the dimensions of the X Window with this XID?

What I have managed so far is to use

```
XWindowAttributes attr;
if (::XGetWindowAttributes(display_, xid, &attr))
```

But this gives me the position relative to the decorator window around the widget. But what I want is the absolute position

Comment: I don't think there's any single API to get what you want but using `XQueryTree` in conjunction with `XGetWindowAttributes` (or `XGetGeometry`) should allow you to work your way from the known window id back up the window hierarchy to the root, adjusting the geometry as you go.

Comment: The solution is to use `XTranslateCoordinates`, then you can translate them relative to the root window.

Comment: @Nidhoegger Post it as an answer and mark it accepted.